# Dojo grid not scrolling to last item

Tags: dojo, grid

I'm teaching myself javascript by building a very basic web based chat application.

Chat messages are posted to a web server.  An HTML chat Client polls the web server periodically to download any new messages.

The chat messages are displayed using a dojo grid.

My problem is that I can't scroll the grid to the last message.  I have tried using scrollToRow but it doesn't work.

The javascript code is here =>

```
<html>  
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "./dojoroot/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
        @import "./dojoroot/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
        @import "./dojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css";
        @import "./dojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css";
        .input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: justify;
        }
        .dojoxGridHeader {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <script language="JavaScript" src="./dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="isDebug: false, parseOnLoad: true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/Javascript">
        dojo.require("dojo.parser");
        dojo.require("dojo.dom-style");
        dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
        dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
        var chatData={items:[]};
        var chatStore=new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data:chatData});
        var chatLayout=[[{'name':'Sender','field':'sender','width':'10%'},
                         {'name':'Message','field':'message','width':'90%'}]];
        var chatRow=0;
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" sizeMin="10" sizeShare="10">
            <div id="gridDiv" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #aaa; width:98%; height:80%; overflow:auto;">
            </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var grid=new dojox.grid.DataGrid({id:'grid',
                                          store:chatStore,
                                          structure:chatLayout,
                                          rowSelector:'0px'});
        grid.placeAt("gridDiv");
        grid.startup();
        setInterval(listenToServer,250);

        function listenToServer() {
            dojo.xhrGet({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/ChatProject/ListenToServer",
                handleAs: "json",
                load: function(data) {
                    if (data!=null) {
                        if (data.message!="") {
                            var myNewItem = {sender: data.sender, message: data.message};
                            chatRow++;
                            // Insert the new item into the store:
                            // (we use store3 from the example above in this example)
                            chatStore.newItem(myNewItem);
                            chatStore.save();
                            var lastRow=grid.store._arrayOfAllItems.length-1;
                            grid.scrollToRow(lastRow);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });             
        }
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

The grid does not scroll down to the last message.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

James.

Comment: try calling a resize after the rows have been added.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion but I'm afraid it didn't work.  I added grid.resize() immediately after chatStore.save() but the grid stopped displaying anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

After much experimentation I discovered the following issues:

1. two separate scroll bars were being created - I assume (although I am not sure) that one scroll bar was associated with the content pane and one with the grid.  For the grid I set overflow:hidden to overcome this.
2. the height:80% parameter was causing the grid to be bigger than the surrounding content pane.  I changed this to height:250px.

With these two changes the scrolling started to work (almost).

At this point I encountered this bug in dataGrid => https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10487

At that point I moved on and stopped using dataGrid!

Comment: dojo shouldn't be used. Never. Under any circumstance. It's a hallamark of terrible software.